# Watch command does not work anymore

Tags: command-line, bash

I used linux command `watch sensors` to watch my sensors before. However I have installed many packages and now `watch` command watches for changes in current directory.
How can I run `watch sensors` as before? (I would prefer to have stayed the new watch directory command)

```
~# type -a watch
watch is /usr/local/bin/watch
watch is /usr/bin/watch

~$ dpkg -S $(which watch)
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/watch

~# apt-cache policy procps
procps:
  Installed: 1:3.3.9-1ubuntu2.2
  Candidate: 1:3.3.9-1ubuntu2.2
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.3.9-1ubuntu2.2 0
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.3.9-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Seems like watch now is a node.js script. How can I run linux watch command?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `type watch` and `dpkg -S $(which watch)`.

Comment: Seems you have installed `watch` locally..the question is whether the `watch` from `procps` is still there....What are the outputs of `apt-cache policy procps` and `type -a watch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen, your `PATH` contains `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, hence the `watch` you have installed by compiling locally (`/usr/local/bin/watch`) is having the precedence over original `watch` (`/usr/bin/watch`). Another very unlikely case is that `/usr/bin` is not in your `PATH`.

You have some solution options now:

- Rename the local `watch` (`/usr/local/bin`) as something else, given renaming won't create any problem
- Edit your `PATH` to have `/usr/bin` before `/usr/local/bin`, again if would create no problem:

  ```
  PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:.....
  ```
- Make an alias:

  ```
  alias watch=/usr/bin/watch
  ```
- Use full path:

  ```
  /usr/bin/watch
  ```

Comment: Great answer. I have chosen option 1 (renamed /usr/local/bin/watch to fs_watch